# What am I? According to the public, they describe me as 'bold'

Tags: riddle

Try and guess the object I am describing:

> According to the public,
>       they describe me as 'bold'
>       though my job is to get hit,
>       by my 'clapping' partner
>       while I scream my pain.
>       I can be highly religious,
>       or I just hang around shops
>       jumping and shrieking whenever
>       a door opens.

What am I? This is quite cryptic so you'll need to think outside the box!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm having trouble with the first clue, but:

> You're a bell.

According to the public,
they describe me as 'bold'

> Bradley Bell was the executive producer of The Bold and the Beautiful?  Bell is also a font, which can be bold.

though my job is to get hit,
by my 'clapping' partner
while I scream my pain.

> The clapper hangs inside a bell and hits it to make it ring.  It's also called a tongue.

I can be highly religious,
or I just hang around shops
jumping and shrieking whenever
a door opens.

> It can be a church bell, or the bells that ring to signify that a customer had entered the store.

Comment: Correct! Not quite with the first clue-The term is 'As bold as brass' and most bells are made of brass. Hadn't thought of your idea though

Comment: I just googled "bold bell" :)

Comment: @JoeBeastlyGerbil According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell#Bellmaking) bells are more commonly bronze!

Comment: Oh, ok. Is there an expression to do with bronze @Samthere or anyone else?

Comment: Always on schedule, but never first or second?

Comment: @JoeBeastlyGerbil No idea; it's close enough that I wouldn't worry too much for a riddle. I don't know of any bronze phrases.

Answer (score 5):

Is it

> a bell? Or more specifically, the 'cup' part of the bell?

```
According to the public,
they describe me as 'bold'
```

> Not really sure about that one.

```
though my job is to get hit,
by my 'clapping' partner
while I scream my pain.
```

> Bells are rung by the 'clapper' hitting the cup.

```
I can be highly religious,
```

> Bells are found in church bell towers, so religious, and literally high off the ground.

```
or I just hang around shops
jumping and shrieking whenever
a door opens.
```

> And there are also bells that are attached to shop doors to ring when someone enters.

Comment: Correct! The first clue, as most bells are made of brass, is the phrase 'As bold as brass'

Answer (score 3):

You're...

> a bell!
>  Bells are supposed to be hit by their clappers. Many shops have bells on the doors to alert employees when a customer enters, and many churches use bells too.

Comment: Correct! Also with the second line, 'I' am described as bold. You are probably familiar with the phrase 'As bold as brass', and most bells are made of brass, harder clue that one.

Comment: @Joe Never heard it.

Comment: Oh, ok well you got the rest!